# Play 2 thread pools : default pool VS Akka Pool with Java

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

According to the documentation, the easier way to use an actor is :

> Promise promiseOfInt = Akka.future(   new Callable()
>   {
>       public Integer call() {
>         return ... ;
>       }   } );

But the doc also says that with the Java API it will always use the same thread pool (play default thread pool).

The documentation says that there is also an Akka pool for actors.
How can I send this actor tasks to the Akka thread pool, not to block common user actions?
So I would be able to tune the Akka pool and keep the default pool small.

Thanks, 
Loic

Comment: Did you check the [Play thread pools doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ThreadPools) ?

Comment: Yes I did, that's the reason why I've asked this question.
I find it ambiguous, there is an Akka pool for actors but the doc also says that with the Java API it will always use the same thread pool (play default thread pool).

Comment: You can create a custom ExecutionContext (ie custom pool of Actors), and call directly the Akka API to use it: http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.1.2/akka/dispatch/Futures.html#future(java.util.concurrent.Callable, scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext) and http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/java/futures.html

Comment: Thanks! I will check that :)

Comment: But I would prefere to use the provided Akka pool rather than create my own execution context...

Comment: I don't really know if there is a separated pool for Akka actors ? Check the reference config: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.1/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/reference.conf

Comment: In the Play thread pool documentation : "Akka thread pool - This is used by the Play Akka plugin, and can be configured the same way that you would configure Akka." But yes it's not clear if it's provided or if I must configure it as explained in the links you've posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java **Akka** plugin (`play.libs.Akka`) forwards to the Scala plugin (`play.api.libs.Akka`), which in turn starts a new Actor system based on the app's configuration. (That's all the plugin does.)

So you would configure that ActorSystem and all its dispatchers (a dispatcher is also an ExecutionContext) using your normal application.conf file based on the `akka` config key. These dispatchers are the thread pools the documentation is referring to.

The **default thread pool** is used when you import `play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.default`. This is a Scala-only API. In Java, this ExecutionContext is always used automatically as soon as you touch futures and promises. This thread pool is actually based on Play's internal actor system, configured via the `play` config key.

So in summary, all your actors, when created via the Akka plugin's ActorSystem, will automatically use the Akka thread pool (inside an actor you can refer to that using `context.dispatcher`).

Outside actors, you will be using Play's default/internal thread pool.